# C++ windows services

Tags: c++, directory, windows-services, access-control

Is there a way to restrict a c++ windows service from calling an exe that is outside the directory where the exe of the service is present.

For example, let us say a folder contains 4 exe's

a.exe, b.exe, c.exe and c++service.exe

c++service.exe is running as a service. How to restrict this service from calling any other exe other than a.exe,b.exe,c.exe.

Comment: "How to restrict this service from calling any other exe other than a.exe,b.exe,c.exe" - Ehh, write c++service.exe in a way where it never looks outside it's working directory and never tries to run executables named anything except `a`, `b` or `c`? This smells very much like a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you *actually* trying to *achieve*?

Comment: I dont want to hardcode it on service code. I want the directory to behave in such a way. That it doesnt allow the service inside it to call exe outside it.